# Programming an application using jQuery only?

Tags: jquery

Is there someone out there who can explain to me if jQuery can be an application by itself? An example if we can create a web application alone using jQuery? Because we're having a discussion and someone in the office expressed that jQuery can be used as an application.
Any help or idea is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can have a JavaScript web-application that executes in the browser. jQuery is merely a script which provides additional API to JavaScript.

Comment: It depend of your requirements, If you provide it maybe we can provide some feedback

Comment: the requirement, a web application, that has UI and can access a database. Do you think jQuery can do this alone?

Comment: @KG Sosa Where is the database? On a web-server? In what format?

Comment: @Šime Vidas let's just say the db is on the web-server, ms sql server format

Comment: @KGSosa jQuery runs in the browser. You can send HTTP-requests with jQuery and I'm pretty sure you can't access contents of a MSSQL database via HTTP-requests alone - you need a server-side language.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it's possible (depending upon what the 'app' needs to do). But you probably shouldn't!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, jQuery (being javascript) can handle all sorts of programming logic but everything would be client side (including the authentication to your database etc ...). At that point, you would have a very insecure application.

Possible ... yes. Practical and feasible ... no.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in nodejs (http://nodejs.org/). It's a webserver in javascript ;) As jQuery is an extension of javascript I guess you can use that too for nodejs. Never tried it though.

For a webpage, you'll still need html / css for the static content.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you are using a client-server setup which means that you cannot build an application using JavaScript only (you'll need some server side code to handle postbacks, acces your database, etc). On the other hand, I you can acces your data feeds (XML files for example) from the client code (javascript), you can easily build a whole website on top of it. jQuery is not something that belongs in this question because it is just a framework build on top of JavaScript. So the question should be "Can I build an application using JavaScript only?". In short, the answer is yes..but it's not very common.